# JavaFX: How do I achieve 'no default focused button'

Tags: java, button, javafx

I'm new to JavaFX and I'm making my first application a simple hangman game, as it is something I've done before in swing.

In the game, I have constructed a keyboard, but I can't figure out how to make all of my buttons 'not focused' when the game starts, so it looks like this

[image]

Notice how the 'Q' is darkened. I considered a jankey approach, like having a button outside the scene that does nothing but acts as default focus button, but I would really like to know the correct way to do this. All my research has only told how to make a specific button focused.

Thanks a ton to anyone willing to help.

Comment: The default behavoiur is the first focus traversable node getting the focus. You could of course make the buttons non-focus-traversable, but I guess this is not what you want to do?

Comment: Not exactly (I had to look that up), but thank you for the reference. I'm still learning different tools and options.

Comment: I haven't tried it but I am guessing that given the focus to the root node will achieve your desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what @Sedrick mentioned is correct. You can just focus on any layout node by default.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DefaultFocusDemo extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setSpacing(20);
        Scene sc = new Scene(root, 500, 500);
        primaryStage.setScene(sc);
        primaryStage.show();


        ToggleButton btn1 = new ToggleButton("Button 1");
        ToggleButton btn2 = new ToggleButton("Button 2");
        ToggleButton btn3 = new ToggleButton("Button 3");
        ToggleButton btn4 = new ToggleButton("Button 4");

        HBox hb1 = new HBox();
        hb1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        hb1.getChildren().addAll(btn1, btn2);

        HBox hb2 = new HBox();
        hb2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        hb2.getChildren().addAll(btn3, btn4);

        root.getChildren().addAll(hb1, hb2);

        hb1.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

Comment: I requested focus on the root scene and it turned out to be the most elegant solution I've tried. Thank you for you assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea. Create an off-screen button and make sure it has starting focus.

Comment: Should cycle through that node as well though, if you move the focus to the next node having focused the last button....